# Python: dynamic column sum for each row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe with 2 identifiers (ID1, ID2) and 3 numeric columns (X1,X2,X3) and a column titled 'input' (total 6 columns) and n rows. For each row, I want to get the index of the nth column such that n is the last time that (x1+x2+xn... >=0) is still true.

How can I do this in Python?

In R I did this by using:

```
tmp = data


for (i in 4:5)

{

data[,i]<-  tmp$input - rowSums(tmp[,3:i])

}

output<-  apply((data[,3:5]), 1, function(x) max(which(x>0)))

data$output <-  output
```

I am trying to translate this into Python. What might be the best way to do this? There can be N such rows, and M such columns.

Sample Data:

```
ID1 ID2 X1  X2  X3  INPUT   OUTPUT  (explanation)       
a   b   1   2   3   3   2   (X1 = 1, x1+x2 = 3, x1+x3+x3 = 6 ... and after 2 sums, input< sums)     
a1  a2  5   2   1   4   0   (X1 = 5, x1+x2 = 7, x1+x3+x3 = 8 ... and even for 1 sum, input< sums)   
a2  b2  0   4   5   100 3   (X1=0, X1+X2=4, X1+X2+X3=9, ... even after 3 sums, input>sums)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pandas module which handles this very effectively in Python.

```
import pandas as pd
#Taking a sample data here
df = pd.DataFrame([
              ['A','B',1,3,4,0.1],
            ['K','L',10,3,14,0.5],
            ['P','H',1,73,40,0.6]],columns = ['ID1','ID2','X2','X3','X4','INPUT'])
 #Below code does the functionality you would want.
df['new_column']=df[['X2','X3','X4']].max(axis=1)
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Hi Jim, I don't think this is what I am looking for. If you look at your sample data, input column needs different values, say they are 5, 10, 100. For the first row, if input =5, [X2=1, X2+X3 = 4, X2+X3+x4 =8]. The maximum index in this case will be  3(X3) because after that the any subsequent sum will give sum>input.    For second row if input = 10, X2= 10, X2+X3= 13, X2+X3+X4=27. Here the output = 2 (X2) after X2 or the first column itself, if there is a subsequent addition, the sum is always greater than 10 (input.). Does that help with some context?

Comment: Can you print your input and output in the question. That will be great.